# How to iterate list inside hashtable key with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, list, hashtable

I have a list of strings (List) that I populated with pictures(in my code-behind). Then I store it in a Hashtable with a key of "sbPrints" which then gets returned to the ajax call.

However I don't know how to iterate the list inside that specific key in javascript.

the hastable containing the list in javascript looks like this : `h['sbPrints'].`

the reason I'm asking about this is because if I just do

```
$('#prints').val(h['sbPrints']);
```

then I end up with unwanted commas in between each picture.

EDIT:how the hashtable gets populated

iny my code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Hashtable getPersonInfo(int personID)
{
     Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
     SqlDataReader drThumbs;
     drThumbs = comGetThumbs.ExecuteReader();
     List<string> fingerPrints = new List<string>();
     while(drThumbs.Read())
     {
          fingerPrints.Add("<div class=\"fingerprints\"><img alt='prints' src='../ShowThumbnail.ashx?BFID=" + drThumbs["BinaryFileID"].ToString() + "'/><div><label><a class=\"finger\" href='../DownloadFile.aspx?id=" + drThumbs["BinaryFileID"].ToString() + "'>" + drThumbs["FileName"].ToString() + "</label></div></div>");
     }
}
```

Then in my javascript file I make an ajax call to the the method and populate my
asp controls with the data from the hashtable.

Comment: Is the hashtable returned as a string?

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit further on how you are populating `h['sbPrints']`

Comment: What _exactly_ does `h['sbPrints']` contain?

Comment: i'll post it in the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but how about this:

```
$.each(h['sbPrints'], function(i, v) {
  $('#prints').val(v);
});
```

This will iterate through every item in `h['sbPrints']` and pass them to your `prints` selector's jQuery value function. I don't really know why you would want to do this, as `$.each` will replace the value in each iteration.

Perhaps what you mean is that `h['sbPrints']` is an array and when it's stringified, your browser will insert commas between the items. If you just want the list without commas, then you can do this:

```
$('#prints').val(h['sbPrints'].join(''));
```

Comment: thank you. I have no idea why I never thought of .join... I knew the data got presented as an array and that it adds a , if you don't iterate it.